# 3 column layout with sticky header

Tags: css

How would I do the following layout in pure css.

3 columns with percentage based width, not px.

and a sticky header that is only in the middle column, not left/right.

When scrolling, over any! of the 3 column, only content in the middle column scrolls. Kind of how twitters layout is.

edit:
this is what i got so far, the sticky header wont stick. when i scroll to the bottom, it "disappears"
https://jsfiddle.net/pkrbc7dm/

```css
html,body{height:100%}
.wrap{width:100%;height:100%;position:relative}
.left,.right{width:20%;top: 0; bottom: 0px;position: fixed;}
.left,.center,.right,.bodywrap{height:100%}
.center{margin:0 20%;}
.left{left:0}
.right{right:0}

.left{background-color:#aaa}
.right{background-color:#ccc}

.head2{
  background-color:tomato;
  width:100%;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='left'>left</div>
  <div class='right'>right</div>
  <div class='center'>
    <div class="head2">HEADER</div>
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
    hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, hello world, 
  </div>
</div>
```

see below picture for what i mean

[image]

thank you

Comment: Can you post a [mre] of what you've tried?

Comment: added my attempt, sorry guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I believe this is what you asked. All parts using percentage based width, with the same layout, and only the main content scrolling.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.left-column {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: lightblue;
  top: 0;
}

.right-column {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.main-content {
  margin: 0% 25%;
  width: 50%;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.content>img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-column"></div>
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="topbar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/862-8628237_random-image-from-user-minecraft-logo-coloring-pages.png">
    <img src="https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/862-8628237_random-image-from-user-minecraft-logo-coloring-pages.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-column"></div>
```

Comment: this is great thank you. only thing is i dont know the height of the topbar so it if would go inside the main-content flow, that would do the trick

Comment: @FrankUnderwood it won't change anything, since it's position is fixed, but okay.. I edited it to be inside the content!

Comment: @FrankUnderwood yah, it does a change a bit. I changed it and made it to fit perfectly, distinguish the topbar from the actual content. I believe you want something like how I edited!

Comment: yes now it is exactly as i need it :)

Answer (score 0):

**the recipe:** flex, position: sticky, overflow.

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
}

.w {
  display: flex;  
  gap: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.w > div {
  height: 100vh;
  background: gray;  
}

.l, .r {
  width: 20%;
}

.m {
  width: 100%;
}
.l, .r {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;  
}
.r {
  background: blue;
}

.content {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="l">
    left<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>left
  </div>
  <div class="m">
    <div class="h">header</div>
    <div class="content">content content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content content
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
      content content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content content
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
      content content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content content
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
      content content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content contentcontent content content content content      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="r">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. but im trying to get the scrollbar to the very left, and also that you can scroll when mouse is over left and right column.